# Извлечение подстроки из строки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Как с помощью python re, извлечь из строки подстроку начинающуюся с цифры и заканчивающуюся на цифру, с учетом пробелов?

orig_str = "Произведено 3 июля 2010 в Санкт-Петербурге"

Хочу получить: "23 июля 2010"

Comment: `r"\d{1,2} (января|февраля|марта|....|декабря) \d{4}"` (вместо точек допишите остальные месяцы)

Comment: 3 июля или 23 июля?

Comment: Да наверное и попроще достаточно `r"\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+"`, но надо проверять, могут и ложные срабатывания быть )

Comment: `re.search(r'\d.*\d', orig_str)` - регулярные выражения жадные. Из всех строк выберется самая длинная, с цифрами на концах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для надежного поиска нужно не начало/конец описывать, а полностью максимально конкретно описать структуру искомой подстроки, например, условно: одна или две цифры, пробел, несколько букв, пробел, 4 цифры (`r"\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4}"`). Если может быть несколько пробелов и могут быть другие пробельные символы (например, табы), то пробелы нужно заменить на `\s+`.

В идеале в средней части стоит перечислить все месяцы, тогда не будет матчиться на два числа с произвольным словом между ними:

```
import re

orig_str = "Произведено 3 июля 2010 в Санкт-Петербурге" 

result = re.search(r"\d{1,2} (января|февраля|марта|апреля|июня|июля|августа|сентября|октября|декабря) \d{4}", orig_str)                

print(result.group(0))  # 3 июля 2010
```